# MySQL Query: Optimal Querying

Tags: sql, mysql

i have this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT idx_campus_bookinfo,c.userid as Buyer,bookname,book_explain,writedate
FROM campus_bookinfo cb 
LEFT JOIN user_books ub ON idx_campus_bookinfo = id_product
LEFT JOIN customer c ON ub.id_customer = c.id_customer
where cb.idx_campus = 1 and cb.idxuser = 29 ORDER BY writedate DESC
```

which give an output of

[Click to View output](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?189060bec7.jpg)

My Question is how can i make the buyer column to be delimited by comma which has the same book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, but it means having to replace DISTINCT with a GROUP BY:

```
    SELECT idx_campus_bookinfo,
           GROUP_CONCAT(c.userid SEPARATOR ',') as Buyer,
           bookname,
           book_explain,
           writedate
      FROM campus_bookinfo cb 
LEFT JOIN user_books ub ON idx_campus_bookinfo = id_product
LEFT JOIN customer c ON ub.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE cb.idx_campus = 1 
      AND cb.idxuser = 29 
 GROUP BY idx_campus_bookinfo, bookname, book_explain, writedate
 ORDER BY writedate DESC
```

> a followup question, can i sort the userid?

Yes, you can:

```
    SELECT idx_campus_bookinfo,
           GROUP_CONCAT(c.userid ORDER BY c.userid ASC SEPARATOR ',') as Buyer,
           bookname,
           book_explain,
           writedate
      FROM campus_bookinfo cb 
LEFT JOIN user_books ub ON idx_campus_bookinfo = id_product
LEFT JOIN customer c ON ub.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE cb.idx_campus = 1 
      AND cb.idxuser = 29 
 GROUP BY idx_campus_bookinfo, bookname, book_explain, writedate
 ORDER BY writedate DESC
```

Comment: ...seems you beat me to it ;)

Comment: a followup question, can i sort the userid?

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP_CONCAT` will take your user ids and concatenate them. Try this out.

```
SELECT idx_campus_bookinfo,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.userid) as Buyer, bookname, book_explain, writedate
FROM campus_bookinfo cb 
LEFT JOIN user_books ub ON idx_campus_bookinfo = id_product
LEFT JOIN customer c ON ub.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE cb.idx_campus = 1 and cb.idxuser = 29
GROUP BY idx_campus_bookinfo
ORDER BY writedate DESC
```

Comment: That `GROUP BY` is supported by MySQL, but it isn't identical to the OP's query.

Comment: i like your code, coz its much shorter, but first right, first serve..
Thanks anyway hope to here from you both again...